# How to count classification_report ( precision recall f1-score support) in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, machine-learning, classification

I have table with classification result of binary classification.

something like

```
id, predict_value, real_value
1,  true, true
2,  true, false
...
```

I want to get with sql classification_report, something like

```
   class   precision    recall  f1-score   support

   False       0.97      1.00      0.98     57241
    True       0.68      0.22      0.33      2323
accuracy       NULL      NULL      0.97     59564
```

Can you help me with sql query ?

Comment: better would be to add more rows and the exact number for the result, i can't see ti get your results

Comment: Please define the logic you want. What do things like "recall" or "f1-score" mean?

Comment: here are some definitions of precision    recall  f1-score   support
https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/loss-functions-classification

Answer (score 2):

The following might prove useful.

```
WITH classes AS (SELECT my_data.predict_value AS class
                   FROM my_data
                 UNION
                 SELECT my_data.real_value AS class
                   FROM my_data),
     t AS (SELECT c.class,
                  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE c.class = d.predict_value)                                              AS SUPPORT,
                  (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE c.class = d.predict_value AND d.predict_value = d.real_value))::float  AS tp,
                  (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE c.class = d.predict_value AND d.predict_value <> d.real_value))::float AS fp,
                  (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE c.class <> d.predict_value AND c.class <> d.real_value))::float        AS tn,
                  (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE c.class <> d.predict_value AND c.class = d.real_value))::float         AS fn
             FROM classes c
               CROSS JOIN my_data d
             GROUP BY c.class),
     pr AS (SELECT t.class::text                                               AS class,
                   CASE t.support WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE t.tp / t.support END   AS precision,
                   CASE t.support WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE tp / (t.tp + t.fn) END AS recall,
                   t.support
              FROM t
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Accuracy'                          AS class,
                   SUM(t.tp) / SUM(t.support)          AS precision,
                   SUM(t.tp) / (SUM(t.tp) + SUM(t.fn)) AS recall,
                   SUM(t.support)                      AS support
              FROM t)
SELECT pr.class,
       pr.precision,
       pr.recall,
       2 * pr.precision * pr.recall / (pr.precision + pr.recall) AS "f1-score",
       pr.support
  FROM pr
  ORDER BY pr.class;
```

This query works for any positive number of classes, not just binary classification.

Answer (score 1):

I have next ugly sql as soltion

```
with _tmp as (select 'accuracy' as class,
                     null       as pricission,
                     null       as recall,
                     count(*)   as support
              from my_data
              UNION
              select 'True'                                                          as class,
                     (count(*) filter ( where predict_value = True and real_value = True ))::float
                         /
                     (count(*) filter ( where predict_value = True))::numeric(12, 6) as pricission,
                     (count(*) filter ( where predict_value = True and real_value = True ))::float
                         /
                     (
                                     count(*) filter ( where predict_value = FALSE and real_value = True)
                             +
                                     count(*) filter ( where predict_value = True and real_value = True )
                         )::float                                                    as recall,
                     null                                                            as f1_score,
                     count(*) filter ( where predict_value = True)                   as support
              from my_data
              Union
              select 'False'                                                          as class,
                     (count(*) filter ( where predict_value = FALSE and real_value = FALSE ))::float
                         /
                     (count(*) filter ( where predict_value = FALSE))::numeric(12, 6) as pricission,
                     (count(*) filter ( where predict_value = FALSE and real_value = FALSE ))::float
                         /
                     (
                                     count(*) filter ( where predict_value = True and real_value = FALSE)
                             +
                                     count(*) filter ( where predict_value = FALSE and real_value = FALSE )
                         )::float                                                     as recall,
                     null                                                             as f1_score,
                     count(*) filter ( where fixed_predict = FALSE)                   as support
              from my_data)
select "class",
       pricission::numeric(12, 3),
       recall::numeric(12, 3),
       (2 * pricission * recall / (pricission + recall))::numeric(12, 3) as f1_score,
       support
from _tmp
order by support
```